# Intuition for the Cauchy Quantile

Tags: probability, distributions, cauchy-distribution

I've got these two plots, the first is a plot of the cauchy quantile function evaluated at 500 random standard uniforms. The next plot is the cumulative sum of the qunatiles. For example, if elements of the first plot are $x(1), x(2), \cdots,x(500)$. Elements of the second plot are: $y(1) = x(1), y(2)=x(1) + x(2), \cdots ,y(n) = x(1)+\cdots+x(n)$.

I am trying to see whether my code is correct and whether my results are intuitive. Here are the plots:

[image]

If they are correct, are these jumps due to the fact that we have a tan function (in the qunatile function of the cauchy) ? Almost like the tan is a bit unstable in the values it produces? (intuitively not mathematically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is about the heavy tails of the Cauchy distribution. As you can see in the upper plot, when you draw very small or very large uniform r.v.s you get extreme quantiles. Compare

```
qcauchy(.01)
[1] -31.82052
> qcauchy(.001)
[1] -318.3088
> qnorm(.01)
[1] -2.326348
> qnorm(.001)
[1] -3.090232
```

These extreme quantiles then obviously will also have a strong effect on the sum.

Ploting the realizations against the uniform random numbers instead of against the index maybe makes this more transparent:

```
x=runif(500)
plot(x,qcauchy(x))
```

[image]

Comment: A related (and perhaps more penetrating) question is whether the O.P.'s experiment will ever stabilize if it is modified to track the *mean* of the quantiles.  *It will not*--but to see that you would need to provide a more detailed analysis of just how "heavy" the Cauchy tails are. Another way to make this point is to reconsider your argument for a Student $t(1.01)$ distribution (the Cauchy is a Student $t(1)$). Your plot will look almost identical and you will get qualitatively similar behavior in your simulation--*but this time the mean will converge to zero.*